# Can I run my Bosto touch-screen/tablet on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

Is it possible to run my [Bosto Kingtee](http://www.bosto.co/products) 14wa Graphics/touch-screen/tablet on Ubuntu? I can't seem to find any drivers for it. Any advice/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: v1 or v2, looks like someone is working on it on their own forum: http://forum.bosto.co/viewforum.php?f=56&sid=bf3b6ce2e9ca3a939f8e840a639fdb64

Comment: this is a "touch-screen" like a graphire/wacom meant to connect to a regular computer

Comment: @Mateo close vote retracted.